# look like meaning in a sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

> As  people  began  to  go  to  more  places  and  do  more  things,  they  were  more  interested  in knowing  the  correct  time.    By  1900,  almost  every  house  had  a  clock,  and  nearly  every  well-dressed gentleman wore a watch on a chain tucked in his vest pocket.  Today  of  course,  we  have  electric  clocks  that  keep  giving  the  right  time  until  they  are unplugged or  the electricity  goes  off. Scientists have invented clocks that  **look  like**  large machines  and tell the correct time to a split second. The  most  modern  electric  clocks  for  home  use  do  not  have  faces  or  hands. These clocks  are called  digital  clocks,  and  they  tell,  the  time  with  a  set  of  numerals  which  appear  in  a  little  window. The seconds are counted off like the tenths of a mile on the odometer of a car. Many  electric  clocks  are  combined  with  radios,  which  can  sometimes  be  set  to  turn  on automatically.  Thus,  instead  of  an  alarm  ringing  in  your  ear  in  the  morning,  you  can  hear  soft  music playing when it is time to get up. Some clocks will even start the coffee maker! Although  clocks  and  watches  play  an  important  part  in  people's  lives  in  industrialized countries,  time is  still  regarded in very  different  ways in different  parts of  the world.

What does "look like"" mean in this sentence?
Clocks are equal in size with large machines.
or
Clocks are equal in the quality of work with large machine?

Comment: You will need to provide further context. You should give a source for that quote. Without more context, I can't guess if there is a different meaning from the dictionary definition. Regarding the last sentence: clocks are machines, machines can be very small, and clocks can be very big.

Comment: The judgment of "looks-like" is in the eye of the beholder (not necessary logical). Your example needs more context in order to determine if the statement is valid.

Comment: Where did this text come from? We might talk about "[Clocks That Look Like Camera Gear](https://petapixel.com/2014/12/25/roundup-novelty-clocks-designed-look-like-camera-gear/)", but a "[large machine](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=%22large%20machine%22&tbs=imgo:1)" could look like anything, so we wouldn't typically use that to describe something else.

Answer (score 1):

A Google search has turned this text up as "Unit 4 Clocks through Time" and appears to be an English learning text.

> Scientists have invented clocks that **look like** large machines and tell the correct time to a split second.

This can be interpreted as meaning that there are large clocks that have the appearance of some machine, where the purpose of the machine is unknown to the person seeing it. Imagine a steam locomotive in the eyes of a technologically primitive person, they may see it as a large beast with hard skin that roars and hisses, and exhales smoke and flame. The author is trying to convey an image to the reader, where the reader will fill in the details from their own imagination and experience.

A clock that tells the correct time to a split second is not quite like that (looks like a large machine), although perhaps the first atomic clocks were.

FOCS 1 (pictured) is a continuous cold caesium fountain atomic clock in Switzerland which started operating in 2004 at an uncertainty of one second in 30 million years. FOCS 1 is one of the most accurate devices for measuring time in the world. It stands in a laboratory of the Swiss Federal Office of Metrology METAS in Bern.

[image: Atomic Clock FOCS-1 (Switzerland). The primary frequency standard device, FOCS-1, one of the most accurate devices for measuring time in the world. It stands in a laboratory of the Swiss Federal Office of Metrology METAS in Bern.]

Image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_clock#/media/File:FOCS-1.jpg